# Can we describe $ SO_{2}\left(\mathbb{C}\right) $ as a quotient set by a kernel of homeomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

I want to prove that $ SO_{2}\left(\mathbb{C}\right) $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{C}^{\times} $ and I wonder if I can use the first Isomorphism theorem in order to do so.

Can we describe $ SO_{2}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & -b\\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}:a^{2}+b^{2}=1\right\}  $ as the quotient set of some group by the kernel of homeomorphism to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ ?

Comment: Usually, if you want to show that $A/B \simeq C$, then you may try to construct a surjective homomorphism from $A$ to $C$ whose kernel is $B$. Here you just have $\operatorname{SO}_2(\Bbb C)\simeq \Bbb C^\times$, which you can prove by directly construct an isomorphism. Thus I don't understand what you are asking for. Anyway, by "homeomorphism" you probably mean "continuous homomorphism" as homeomorphisms don't always have "kernel".

Comment: You mean "homomorphism", not "homeomorphism", as the latter already has a meaning in topology, and no topology is needed here.